Different filesystem for the same mount point /tmp , when accessed via ssh , on wsl
I have a Debian system running on wsl
> wsl --version
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.61
MSRDC version: 1.2.5326
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.19045.3208

Linux myHost 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Mar 29 23:14:13 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The issue is that I am trying to share resources between same host attached tty's with ssh'd ones. (In my case I am trying to share sessions with tmux )
The ssh sessions seem not to be able to communicate with same host's tty because tmux uses the path /tmp/tmux-1000 by default , and the ssh'd ones seem to not to be aware of what the local ttys are doing.
Digging into it doing ls /tmp I can see that the contents of the directory are different. Local sessions have many files on /tmp while the ssh'd ones very few.
I can see  the ssh'd ones share between them the same /tmp directory but not with the local ones.
First check of all is seeing if it is the actual same system across sessions. They have the same hostname same ip and if doing ps -e , I can see the same processes.
Though I have seen differences on mount points and file systems
I can see the following output from local sessions
$ df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc       263112772 90108896 159565720  37% /

stat /tmp

fakuve@elitebook-x360:~$ stat /tmp
  File: /tmp
  Size: 12288           Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 8,32    Inode: 57345       Links: 314
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2024-10-01 11:35:56.799263192 +0100
Modify: 2024-10-01 11:35:56.259263397 +0100
Change: 2024-10-01 11:35:56.259263397 +0100
 Birth: 2024-09-18 11:01:45.116998400 +0100



While the ssh'd ones
df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            4036036     0   4036036   0% /tmp



stat /tmp
 File: /tmp
  Size: 200         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 0,87    Inode: 1           Links: 10
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2024-10-01 12:12:16.129269469 +0100
Modify: 2024-10-01 11:36:22.119264611 +0100
Change: 2024-10-01 11:36:22.119264611 +0100
 Birth: -


Any explanation on how this may be tackled?
I may change the working directory of tmux to other PATH that doesnt have this issue. Still, I am looking forward finding out about this

Two issues regarding the same
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5703
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5704
A work around for the tmux use case is just assigning the following env to a different non-conflictive path such as adding the following to your .bashrc export TMUX_TMPDIR="/home/myuser/tmp" 

My comment before, it doesnt look like a good practice. It is better to set it to /tmp so export TMUX_TMPDIR="/tmp" , the issue remains on why the tty's spawned by doing wsl on windows (rather than the ones spawned after ssh connection) , the ones under Windows mount the /tmp path on other filesystems that are not tmpfs . That is the question to troubleshoot
